# Char compare in if statements not working properly

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, statements

I have a couple of if statements comparing a private char of a class with a character (like 'c' or 'd'), but it isn't assigning the right value when I run it, and I don't know what the problem is. Here's the code:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const Card &rhs)
{
   string string_suit;
   string string_rank;

   /*switch(rhs.suit)
   {
       case 'c': string_suit="Clubs"; 

       case 'd': string_suit="Diamonds"; 
              break;
       case 'h': string_suit="Hearts"; 
              break;
       case 's': string_suit="Spades"; 
              break;
       default : string_suit= "error"; 
   }*/

   if(rhs.suit == 'c')
   {
      string_suit="Clubs";
   }

   else if(rhs.suit == 'd')
   {
      string_suit ="Diamonds";
   }

   else
   {
      string_suit = "error";
   }


   if(rhs.rank==1)
      string_rank="Ace";

   else if(rhs.rank==11)
      string_rank="Jack";

   else if(rhs.rank==12)
      string_rank="Queen";

   else if(rhs.rank==13)
      string_rank="King";
   else
   {

      ostringstream convert;
      convert << rhs.rank;
      string_rank=convert.str(); //rhs.rank;
   }   

   out<<string_rank<<" of "<<string_suit ;
   return out; 
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger and trace what happens.

Comment: It keeps assigning clubs even though rhs.suit is 'd'.
and the switch statement kept assigning the value of the last case regardless of the value of rhs.suit.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `break;` in your switch statement: So the 'd' case was always executed, even if `rhs.suit` is 'c'. However, the if statement would've worked always correctly.

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const Card &rhs){
    string string_suit;
    string string_rank;
    switch(rhs.suit)
    {
        case 'c': string_suit="Clubs"; 
                  break;
        case 'd': string_suit="Diamonds"; 
                  break;
        case 'h': string_suit="Hearts"; 
                  break;
        case 's': string_suit="Spades"; 
                  break;
        default : string_suit= "error"; 
    }

    if(rhs.rank==1)
      string_rank="Ace";
    else if(rhs.rank==11)
      string_rank="Jack";
    else if(rhs.rank==12)
      string_rank="Queen";
    else if(rhs.rank==13)
      string_rank="King";
    else {
      ostringstream convert;
      convert << rhs.rank;
      string_rank=convert.str(); //rhs.rank;
    }   
    out<<string_rank<<" of "<<string_suit ;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Um, the `switch` statement is commented out. And if it wasn't, the result would be that the suit would **never** be `"Clubs"`, while the problem, according to the comment, is that it's **always** `"Clubs"`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I assumed his original problem (why he commented out the `switch` statement) was the missing `break`, because in the `if` statement itself there is no mistake. The information that always `"Clubs"` is assigned, was added after I had written this answer - the only reason why "Clubs" could be assigned is that `rhs.suit` is assigned to `c` in not shown code.

Comment: Yes, the information was added after you wrote your answer. Nevertheless, the added information makes your answer wrong.